# Write to dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

**The problem:**

I created a dynamic array using pointers and successfully opened a text file to read the number of integers into an int pointer. Now I am trying to store the items from the text file sequentially into the array.

```
int * x;
x = new int;
*x = 0;

int * arraySize;
arraySize = new int;
*arraySize = 0;

int * temp;
temp = new int;
*temp = 0;

// The arraySize is populated. It's not zero when this runs.

int * intArray; // The output is the same even if I set equal to something

intArray = new (nothrow) int[*arraySize];

if (intArray == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
else
{
    do
    {
        file >> *temp;
        intArray[*x] = *temp;
        *x = *x + 1;
        cout << intArray[*x];

    } while (*x < *arraySize);
```

The above uses cout to show me test output, which only produces a memory address (the same memory address repeatedly for all the array positions).

```
-842150451
```

**The desired behavior:** *(since it clearly wasn't obvious to the people who removed it as "off topic" )*

The dynamic array should populate with integers from the text file

**What I tried:**

Using this approach sets each and every array element to the integer 27, which happens to be the last number in the text file.

```
file >> *temp;
intArray[*x] = *temp;
cout << intArray[*x] << endl;
*x = *x + 1;
```

Adding a different number to the end of the text file just changes what number is sent to all positions of the array.

Using this outside of the loop:

```
cout << "\n" << intArray[5];
```

Displays that same number no matter what index position is used.

So my real problem seems to be that I can't assign a different value to each array position.

Using this approach:

```
int* intArray = new int[*arraySize];
```

Is the same as this:

```
int * intArray; // The output is the same even if I set equal to something
intArray = new (nothrow) int[*arraySize];
```

And it doesn't actually solve the problem.

An example program that reproduces the problem (I personally consider it to be wrong to post an entire program, but every single person who answered was incapable of providing an answer. They insisted the problem was elsewhere in the program so I was forced to expand the question):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int * arraySize;
    arraySize = new int;
    *arraySize = 483;

    int * temp;
    temp = new int;
    *temp = 0;

    int * x = 0;
    x = new int;
    *x = 0;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");

    int* intArray = new int[*arraySize];

    if (intArray == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            file >> *temp;
            intArray[*x] = *temp;
            cout << intArray[*x] << endl;
            *x = *x + 1;

        } while (*x < *arraySize);

        cout << "\n" << intArray[5];

        delete[] intArray;

        cout << "\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you run the above COMPLETE program as an empty console project without any text files it will list all zeros. If you give it a test.txt file it will list the LAST number in the file.

Again, the **DESIRED BEHAVIOR:** I am trying to populate the array with ALL the items of the text file.

I am aware that I am using more pointers than is common, and I am aware that everyone who answered thinks the problem was in some other section of code, but that's not the case and I was able to solve my own problem.

This question should not be removed or put on hold because, at least as originally written, it was clear and to the point about a specific problem. I had no choice but to add details because a number of users who didn't know what they were doing were voting the question down.

Comment: I don't know if it is "the" problem, but it is "a" problem: too many pointers!

Comment: Why is everything in your code a pointer? If you would post actual code instead of a snippet that has no hope of compiling, someone might be willing to help you improve it.

Comment: Ah, that's too much pointers. You're outputting the content of `donationsArray`, but I can't see that array being assigned to or declared anywhere in your snippet. Can you show us how you allocate all these variables?

Comment: I don't have a choice. This class assignment requires that EVERY freaking variable is set as a pointer.

Comment: donationsarray was a typo in copying it over. I meant to change both to intArray for readability reasons. Suffice to say, there are no uninitialized elements.

Comment: Can you post the *whole* code to a pastebin? Guess it's the only way to help you.

Comment: Don't use pastebin or anything else off site. When they shuffle their index or delete old, unused pages your question and it's answers are rendered useless. If you can't put your code in the question, that's a good hint your code is too big and [you should work at making an MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user4581301 My idea is that the relevant code can be then pasted in the answer. Though I agree with you in general. Still, s questions like this one can only be solved with a dump of the whole codebase (which means they probably don't belong to SO, but that's a separate problem).

Comment: You have all the code. Seriously, `*arraySize = 483;` there. Why cant you guys believe me? voting down just because you guys cant figure it out isnt helpful.

Comment: Try to believe me when I say that there is NOTHING else to look at here. There are no uninitialized elements, there is no other section of code acting on this, there are no compile errors, it's just not populating the array correctly. That's it. Do you have any idea how stupidly frustrating it is to have a single simple question and to deal with a group of people who want to look everywhere EXCEPT where you need help?

Comment: There, I updated the question with an ENTIRE program that I wrote specifically to focus the question. No other snippets of code exist in the program so you can stop trying to steer the question away from focus.

Comment: See? This is why I didn't want to post an ENTIRE program. Now the whole question is put ON HOLD even though it was specific!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. As I kept saying, the problem was in how I was populating the array. Here's an entire section of code using a `for` loop which correctly populates my pointer array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int * arraySize;
    arraySize = new int;
    *arraySize = 483;

    int * temp;
    temp = new int;
    *temp = 0;

    int * x = 0;
    x = new int;
    *x = 0;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");

    int* intArray = new int[*arraySize];

    for (* x = 0; *x < *arraySize; (*x = *x + 1))
    {
        file >> *temp;
        intArray[*x] = *temp;

        cout << intArray[*x] << endl;
    }

    delete[] intArray;

    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are reading the input into `*temp`.

```
        file >> *temp;
```

You are assigning `*temp` to `intArray[*x]`

```
        intArray[*x] = *temp;
```

You are incrementing `*x`.

```
        *x = *x + 1;
```

Now you are printing `donationsArray[*x]` to `cout`.

```
        cout << donationsArray[*x];
```

I don't see any code that assigns a value to `donationsArray[*x]` before it is printed to `cout`.

It looks like you are printing the contents of an uninitialized array element.

**Update**

Changing the line

```
        cout << donationsArray[*x];
```

to

```
        cout << intArray[*x];
```

is more helpful. However, it is still uninitialized. Remember that you already incremented `*x` before printing `intArray[*x]` to `cout`. What you need is switch those lines.

```
        file >> *temp;
        intArray[*x] = *temp;
        cout << intArray[*x];
        *x = *x + 1;
```

Comment: Of course you don't see any assignments. I only showed a code snippet. There are NO uninitialized items though. the donationsarray is a typo in copying it over though.

Comment: the cout only exists for testing output. When I switch it around it sets every value to 27, which is not a memory address, but still not right. 

Looking at the text file though, 27 is the last integer to be loaded, so it's an improvement at least.

Comment: adding this `cout << "\n" << donationsArray[5];` (or any other array position) gives 27, which means that for some reason it's not incrementing properly. One thing I learned was that using `x++;` on a pointer is supposed to increment the array pointer (while *x++ increments a value), which is something I tried earlier, but that approach caused an access violation.

Comment: @Elliander, I would try `cout << intArray[*x] << endl;` to make sure each number is printed on a separate line.

Comment: Using endl just forces the output to be on one line each. Again, cout is just there to help debug it. Outside of the loop I can access any array element and it is the same. Right now, every part of the array is assigned 27, which is the last integer in the text file, which means that the problem is in the variable used for the index.

Comment: @Elliander, that's we it is useful to post an MCVE. It's hard to see what's happening with your code with bits and pieces of code. Looking at all of the code you've posted, I don't see where `*arraySize` is assigned a value that's different than the initial value of 0..

Comment: That's irrelevant. If I posted every snippet of code it would destroy readability. (every time I add a pointless snippet someone wants to see more and more and go off in side directions) If you need to know, the arraySize is currently 483 which is equal to the number of integers in the text file. I'm trying to focus on the problem I am actually having, and I'd like to avoid opening the doors to more "you are using too many pointers" comments. More importantly, the last time I posted too much code I never got an answer that actually helped and ultimately had to post my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you can create an array using pointers as

```
int* ar = new int[10];
```

You seem to be overusing pointers.

Also, don't forget to free the memory allocated for the array using

```
delete[] ar;
```

Comment: Of course I am over using pointers. If it was up to me I wouldn't use them at all for regular variables. I appreciate the shorter approach to declaring the pointer array, much cleaner, but doesn't actually solve the problem.